# bind 9 and multiple domain names

Tags: centos-6, bind

I have been told the following from someone after trying to get more than one domain name (zone) to work on the same BIND instance. We are able to get a single domain name "example.com" working but cannot get a second domain "example2.com" to work. After research by my co-worker it was determined that BIND 9 does not support multiple domain names. The caveat I was told is if you have more than one interface, you can connect that domain name to the IP on that other interface.

BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1;
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

We have been using BIND for years and never had a problem. Is there any documentation (I looked at the isc docs and did not see it spelled out) to prove/disprove this assertion?

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 2):

This is plain nonsense. Multiple zones per DNS server are supported in BIND 9.x, have been supported since the *earliest* BIND releases, and every single other DNS server (that I've seen) supports this as well.

- The **BIND 9 [Administrator Reference Manual](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.html)** does talk about "some zones" (plural) in [chapter 1](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch01.html#id2567565), and even includes an example configuration for three zones on a single server in [chapter 3](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch03.html#id2567997).

  > The BIND name server can simultaneously act as a master for some zones, a slave for other zones, and as a caching (recursive) server for a set of local clients.
- Going back in time, the **[BIND 4.8 source code](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind4/src/DEPRECATED/4.8/bind-4.8.tar.gz) dated 1987 has an example configuration file "named.boot" that lists three separate zones** and a copy of [RFC 883](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc883) which again talks about a server having multiple zones in the introduction.
- There is also *no reason* in DNS itself for a one-zone-per-IP limit, as the full domain name gets sent in each query, after all, so the server always knows what it should reply with.

  *(Maybe the coworker was thinking of HTTPS on older systems before TLS SNI became widespread?)*

You say you cannot get a second domain name to work. Please post a [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) and describe the "not working" part in less vague terms (e.g. receiving error messages, wrong answers to queries, etc.), maybe post some BIND syslog messages or `dig` output showing the problems.

Comment: Thanks.. I purposely did not expand on what did not work since I was mainly concerned about whether it was supported or not. Thank you so much.